# Tcl: How to get value from array when Myarray is a variable?

Tags: tcl

I have many files that needed to be processed:

I'm using array names to get information in these, using proc like this:

```
proc array_proc {f} {
global f_name
set f_name [file tail $f]
set mtime  [file mtime $f]
set date   [clock format $mtime -format %D]
global $f_name

array set $f_name [list time $mtime]
}
```

```
set files [list /home/dir1/a.txt /home/dir2/b.txt]
foreach f {files} {
array_proc $f
puts "$f $f_name $$f_name(time) $$f_name(date)"
}
```

```
##I want my variables and output like this: (mtime and date is just random example here)
$f $f_name $$f_name(time) $$f_name(date)
/home/dir1/a.txt a.txt 4123123 03/07/2012
/home/dir2/b.txt b.txt 5123123 03/02/2011
```

The problem is, I want to have Myarray as a f_name variable, because there's many files, so the data would be like: `a.txt(time) a.txt(date) b.txt(time) b.txt(date)`, and it use only the f_name variable in my foreach loop

But I don't know how to subsitute the f_name variable first so I could get the array value of that particular f_name array.

Answer (score 1):

`$$f_name(time)`

Tcl doesn't do double substitution (without commands like `eval`).

Two ways to handle this dynamic array name:

1. use the `array get` command

   ```
   [array get $f_name time]
   ```
2. use the 1-argument `set` command (for which `$` expansion is "syntactic sugar")

   ```
   [set [set f_name](time)]
   ```

---

But it's the dynamic variable name that is making this hard. A couple of ways around this as well

- setting up this demo:

  ```bash
  $ touch -t 202301010000 a.txt
  $ touch b.txt
  $ ls -l *.txt
  -rw-r--r-- 1 glennj glennj 0 Jan  1 00:00 a.txt
  -rw-r--r-- 1 glennj glennj 0 Mar  8 14:17 b.txt
  ```

1. Use just one array for the file metadata, putting the file tail as part of a compound key

   ```
   proc array_proc_2 {f} {
       global file_info
       set fname [file tail $f]
       set mtime [file mtime $f]

       set file_info($fname,time) $mtime
       set file_info($fname,date) [clock format $mtime -format %D]
   }
   array_proc_2 ./a.txt
   array_proc_2 ./b.txt
   parray file_info
   puts "b date = $file_info(b.txt,date)"
   ```

   ```
   file_info(a.txt,date) = 01/01/2023
   file_info(a.txt,time) = 1672531200
   file_info(b.txt,date) = 03/08/2023
   file_info(b.txt,time) = 1678285064
   b date = 03/08/2023
   ```
2. use a `dict`

   ```
   proc array_proc_3 {f} {
       global file_stats
       set fname [file tail $f]
       set mtime [file mtime $f]

       dict set file_stats $fname time $mtime
       dict set file_stats $fname date [clock format $mtime -format %D]
   }
   array_proc_3 ./a.txt
   array_proc_3 ./b.txt
   puts $file_stats
   puts "b date = [dict get $file_stats b.txt date]"
   ```

   ```
   a.txt {time 1672531200 date 01/01/2023} b.txt {time 1678285064 date 03/08/2023}
   b date = 03/08/2023
   ```

Comment: You could also have an array of dicts, one per file.

Comment: Thanks very much for the informative answer.
For the 2. I did think of $[set f_name(time)], but forgot about I could have used another set, haha.
I didn't know about the compound key in array, and that's what I'm looking for.
And your dict solution is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You may use tcl command "upvar". By default, tcl procedure is called by value. With upvar, You can get the variable name passed to a procedure. See the following example:

```tcl
proc array_proc { varName } {
    upvar $varName var
    set v1 $var(date)  ;# Get an element
    set var(time) [expr {$v1 + 100}]  ;# Set an element
}

set a(date) 34
set b(date) 56
array_proc a
array_proc b
parray a
parray b
exit

# Output:
# a(date) = 34
# a(time) = 134
# b(date) = 56
# b(time) = 156
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading Glenn and Donal answers, I'm thinking about reformatting my data again, combining the array and dict for something like this:

```
proc file_info_proc {f} {
    global file_info
    set f_name  [file tail $f]
    set mtime   [file mtime $f]
    set date    [clock format $mtime -format %D]

    set file_info($f) "
        f_name  $f_name
        mtime   $mtime
        date    $date
    " 
}

set file_a /home/dir1/a.txt
file_info_proc $file_a
file_info_proc ./b.txt

puts "$file_a [dict get $file_info($file_a) f_name] [dict get $file_info($file_a) date]"
puts $file_info
```

```
/home/dir1/a.txt a.txt 03/07/2023
/home/dir1/a.txt {
        f_name  a.txt
        mtime   1678162276
        date    03/07/2023
    } ./b.txt {
        f_name  b.txt
        mtime   1677036509
        date    02/22/2023
    }
```

The file_info array will store the files, and subsitute the array variable will get me a dict, which I can easily config inside my proc.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Don't define a list with double quotes. If $f_name happens to contain a space then you no longer have a valid dict. `set file_info($f) [list  f_name $f_name  mtime $mtime  date $date]` -- if you want newlines in the list, use *backslash+newline* line continuations

Comment: I'm aware of the issue. I'm planning puts customized files info inside, by using vertical dictionary for future me and colleague to easily looks and modify the dictionary
What do you think about using list for all of variables before putting it in dictionary?
Ex:
`set f_name  [list [file tail $f]]`
`set mtime   [list [file mtime $f]]`

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated